# openssl_encrypt($string, $encrypt_method, $key, 0, $iv) php function equivalent in java?

Tags: java, php, security, encryption, aes

I am using the following encrypt-decrypt logic in frontent site written in PHP and which is impossible to change to another logic-

```
<?php
/**
 * simple method to encrypt or decrypt a plain text string
 * initialization vector(IV) has to be the same when encrypting and decrypting
 * 
 * @param string $action: can be 'encrypt' or 'decrypt'
 * @param string $string: string to encrypt or decrypt
 *
 * @return string
 */
function encrypt_decrypt($action, $string, $secret_key, $secret_iv) {
    $output = false;
    $encrypt_method = "AES-256-CBC";

    // hash
    $key = hash('sha256', $secret_key);

    // iv - encrypt method AES-256-CBC expects 16 bytes - else you will get a warning
    $iv = substr(hash('sha256', $secret_iv), 0, 16);
    if ( $action == 'encrypt' ) {
        $output = openssl_encrypt($string, $encrypt_method, $key, 0, $iv);
        $output = base64_encode($output);
    } else if( $action == 'decrypt' ) {
        $output = openssl_decrypt(base64_decode($string), $encrypt_method, $key, 0, $iv);
    }
    return $output;
}
$plain_txt = "This is my plain text";
echo "Plain Text =" .$plain_txt. "\n";
$encrypted_txt = encrypt_decrypt('encrypt', $plain_txt);
echo "Encrypted Text = " .$encrypted_txt. "\n";
$decrypted_txt = encrypt_decrypt('decrypt', $encrypted_txt);
echo "Decrypted Text =" .$decrypted_txt. "\n";
if ( $plain_txt === $decrypted_txt ) echo "SUCCESS";
else echo "FAILED";
echo "\n";
?>
```

and thats why I have to write equivalent function in Java so that we can use similar logic to encryption and decryption in java. I tried to write encryption logic in java as-

```
    private static String openssl_encrypt(String data, String strKey, String strIv) throws Exception {

        Base64 base64 = new Base64();
        Cipher ciper = Cipher.getInstance("AES/CBC/PKCS5Padding");
        SecretKeySpec key = new SecretKeySpec(Arrays.copyOfRange(strKey.getBytes(), 0, 16), "AES");
        IvParameterSpec iv = new IvParameterSpec(strIv.getBytes("UTF-8"), 0, ciper.getBlockSize());

        // Encrypt
        ciper.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, key, iv);
        byte[] encryptedCiperBytes = base64.encode((ciper.doFinal(data.getBytes())));

        String s = new String(encryptedCiperBytes);
        System.out.println("Ciper : " + s);
        return s;
    }
```

but it is giving me different results while encrypting the same value with the same key and iv.

Can anyone help me in finding the issue with java code and help to write decryption code too?
Thanks in ADV.

Comment: You actual ecnryption key is the SHA256 hash of the key , while that is not the case of the Java Encryption ,please check it